# Jruby not working ClassNotFoundException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I am using rvm , ruby-1.9.3-p547 and jruby-1.7.13.
It was working fine but suddenly something happen I don't know what.
Then after if I run any rails command i.e. bundle install , I got this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rubygems.defaults.OperatingSystemService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jruby.util.JRubyClassLoader.findClass(JRubyClassLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
```

I using Linux.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also I have tried to reinstall ruby and jruby but did't work.

Comment: could you try upgrading to latest 1.7.x (currently 1.7.20) or describe in detail what you're doing and/or possibly share more output if available

Comment: I have tried for latest version but didn't work. `rvm list

rvm rubies

=> jruby-1.7.13 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ missing bin/ruby ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
`   if I run bundle -v without jruby it's works fine but with jruby it's gives above error